# Program bluetooth module (battery powered)

Tags: bluetooth, battery

Im interested in creating my own version of gkchain Gatekeeper seen here https://gkchain.com/. But this will be for Linux since Gatekeeper currently does not support it.

So i know i need to have a transmitter that is battery powered and a universal bluetooth receiver but im not sure where to find such a transmitter dongle that is battery powered. I looked for one from Arduino but i don't seem to see anything related and portable.

looking for some guidance on at least finding a product that matches my needs, if such exists. Im sure i can figure out the programming part myself but finding a dongle that is similar to GateKeeper's is all im looking for at the moment.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative with my own phone. I wrote a python script that just checks for the RSSI of the defined device's MAC (your Phone's Bluetooth MAC) and based on the range that you adjust, it locks/unlocks the PC with `loginctl`.

```
import os, time

your_phone_bluetooth_mac = "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF"
rssi=-15

while True:
    result = os.popen('hcitool rssi %s' % your_phone_bluetooth_mac).read()
    result = (result[19:].strip())
    if (int(result) > rssi):
        os.system("loginctl unlock-session")
    else:
        os.system("loginctl lock-session")
```

I set my RSSI value to what is around 5-10 feet of distance from my bluetooth adapter.

For this to work you must first pair your phone with your computer and must have `loginctl` and `hcitool`. This must be ran with `python3`, i have not tested other versions and you do not have to run as `sudo`. Running the script without sudo will apply to only your session which is probably what you want.

Hope others enjoy this fun script!